# Different ping feedback from seemingly identical LAN machines

Tags: windows, internet, ethernet

LAN of several Windows 10 machines is set up as follows

[image]

The Internet modem is deliberately powered down to eliminate Internet access. The router `192.168.1.1` is powered up. Two machines are wired by Ethernet cables directly into the router's Ethernet ports and set up with static IPs. An extra machine is connected to the router through WiFi with IP issued by the router's DHCP.

When I do

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1
```

from the first machine (`192.168.1.2`) I get the following

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
```

which is what I'd expect. Also, `%errorlevel%` is set to `1` (failure) after this command.

However, when I run the same command from the other two machines I get

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination net unreachable.

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

and `%errorlevel%` remains at `0` (success).

What exactly is going on with these two machines? They seem to report some sort of successful ping. "Sent = 1, Received = 1"? Received from where? Is this somehow normal for Windows `ping` to report "0% loss" in such situations? How does that agree with the "Destination net unreachable" report? What exactly is it referring to?

And what could be the possible difference between the first machine ("Request timed out") and the remaining ones ("Destination net unreachable")? What should I look for? I don't see any differences to speak of in their `ipconfig /all` reports.

All of these machines see their current network as "Private". All of these machines have their Windows Defender Firewall set to "Off" for both "Public" and "Private" networks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows Firewall is configured differently. The second machine's answer is technically "more" correct, because it shows you the ICMP error and not just a timout.

Comment: On all of these machines Windows Defender Firewall is set to "OFF" for both public and private networks.

Comment: The it's the IP-Stack. It's the same answer, but interpreted differently.